# Jquery validation password strength uppercase and lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate, case-sensitive

```
$.validator.addMethod("validpassword", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||
        /^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W]).*$/i.test(value);
}, "The password must contain a minimum of one lower case character," +
           " one upper case character, one digit and one special character..");
```

The above regex does not differentiate between uppercase and lowercase. What's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the `i` flag. It makes the RegEx **case-insensitive**. Also, extend `[\W]` to `[\W_]`.

```
/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W]).*$/i.test(value);
//                                           Remove this   ^

// Ok:
/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W_]).*$/.test(value);
```

Comment: Thanks for poiting out "i" to remvoe case-insensitive from pattern.